# how to pass value from method in angular to property

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I'm trying to pass value from a method to a property

here's my code

I want to pass sub_id_1 to the options under subscription_id

I'm trying for 3 days any help, please

this is a razor integration I'm fetching the response from python and get it back in angular but I fell that I'm locked at buy() method

```
public buy() {
    return this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/razor_sub",{
    }).subscribe(
    (res)=>{
      var rrre = res.json();
      var sub_id_1 = rrre.id;  
      if (sub_id_1) {
        console.log(sub_id_1);
        const type = sub_id_1;
        this.sub_response_id(sub_id_1)
      }
     
    });
    
   }
   /**
    *  sub_response_id
    */
   public  sub_response_id(sub_id_1) {
    this.initPay(sub_id_1)
   }
   
   public options: any = {
    
    key: 'rzp_test_******',
    subscription_id: this.sub_response_id(sub_id_1),
    name: "Acme Corp.",
    description: "Monthly Test Plan",
    image: "#",
    handler: function(response) {
      //alert(response.razorpay_payment_id),
      //alert(response.razorpay_subscription_id),
      //alert(response.razorpay_signature);
    },
    prefill: {
      name: "Tamer Jarrar",
      email: "tamerjrrar@example.com",
      contact: "+919876543210"
    },
    notes: {
      note_key_1: "Tea. Earl Grey. Hot",
      note_key_2: "Make it so."
    },
    theme: {
      color: "#F37254"
    }
  };
  initPay(sub_id_1): void {
    this.rzp = new this.winRef.nativeWindow['Razorpay'](this.options);
    this.rzp.open();
  }

  paymentHandler(res: any) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
buy() {
    return this.http
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/razor_sub", {} )
        .subscribe(res => {
            const { id } = res;  
            if (id) {
                const options = getOptions(id);
                this.initPay(options);
            }
        }
    );
}
   
getOptions(subscription_id) {
    return {
        key: 'rzp_test_******',
        subscription_id,
        name: "Acme Corp.",
        ...
    }
};

initPay(options) {
    this.rzp = new this.winRef.nativeWindow['Razorpay'](options);
    this.rzp.open();
}
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Dmitry thanks a lot that's worked u are a legend really appreciate ur help thanks

Answer (score -1):

i ignore some not-related part of your code, just show the key part of your problem.

you see multiple problems exist in your code to transform some variance to subscription_id.

please reference this:

```
  public buy() {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      debugger;
      var sub_id_1 = 3333;
      if (sub_id_1) {
        console.log("sub_id_1 is", sub_id_1);
        this.options.subscription_id = this.sub_response_id(sub_id_1);
        console.log("subscription_id", this.options.subscription_id);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  /**
   *  sub_response_id
   */
  public sub_response_id(sub_id_1) {
    // this.initPay(sub_id_1);
    return sub_id_1 + 3333;
  }

  public options: any = {
    key: "rzp_test_******",
    subscription_id: 111,
    name: "Acme Corp.",
    description: "Monthly Test Plan",
    image: "#",
    handler: function (response) {
      //alert(response.razorpay_payment_id),
      //alert(response.razorpay_subscription_id),
      //alert(response.razorpay_signature);
    },
    prefill: {
      name: "Tamer Jarrar",
      email: "tamerjrrar@example.com",
      contact: "+919876543210"
    },
    notes: {
      note_key_1: "Tea. Earl Grey. Hot",
      note_key_2: "Make it so."
    },
    theme: {
      color: "#F37254"
    }
  };
```